# Re-populating a JList on an ActionListener event

Tags: java, netbeans, jlist, actionlistener

Depending on what they choose in the JComboBox I want the JList to show different strings, not sure how to repopulate a JList though. When searching through the API, still found nothing.

Any idea on how you might code this?

Im using NetBeans by the way for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not sure how to repopulate a JList
>   though

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel(...);
// add items to the model
list.setModel( model );
```

Or you could use the DefaultComboBoxModel which would allow you to create with model with a Vector or Array.

Answer (score 1):

The `setListData()` method allows you to reset the contents of the list.